# Why can I not connect to DSE nodes running in Docker?

Tags: docker, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to set up a cassandra ring with five nodes in docker using dse-server and dse-studio. The docker containers are up and running and I can access the casandra database and do CRUD operations, but it does not connect to all the nodes. I believe I have not created the docker compose networks correctly or it may be another issue. Here is the code for the project:

https://github.com/juanpujazon/DockerCassandraNodes

If I use the connector connecting to 192.168.3.19:9042 I can do the CRUD for the tables but only the conection to the first node is succesfull. The CRUD completes succesfully, but all the hosts ips other than the first one get the error "Connection[/172.30.0.4:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] Error connecting to /172.30.0.4:9042 (connection timed out: /172.30.0.4:9042)"

I tried to create a connector adding all the ips from the different nodes as contact points but is not working as intended:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to add contact point: "127.0.0.1";"172.30.0.2";"172.30.0.3";"172.30.0.4";"172.30.0.5";"172.30.0.6"
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.addContactPoint(Cluster.java:943)
        at cassandra.java.client.CassandraConnector.connectNodes(CassandraConnector.java:30)
        at cassandra.java.client.Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host desconocido ("127.0.0.1";"172.30.0.2";"172.30.0.3";"172.30.0.4";"172.30.0.5";"172.30.0.6")
        at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:933)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1529)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:852)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1519)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1305)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.addContactPoint(Cluster.java:939)
```

Any idea about what should I change?

Answer (score 0):

If you can only connect to the cluster on `192.168.3.19`, it indicates to me that the containers are not accessible on the host. You will need to configure your Docker environment so that the containers are exposed to public access.

For this error:

```
Connection[/172.30.0.4:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] \
    Error connecting to /172.30.0.4:9042 (connection timed out: /172.30.0.4:9042)
```

you are connecting to the container using the default CQL port `9042` but you've exposed it on a different port in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
        ports:
            - 9044:9042
```

I recommend you re-map all the container ports to just `9042` to make it easier for yourself to connect to them. Otherwise, you'll need to specify the port together with the IP addresses when you configure the contact points like:

```
    "ip1:port1", "ip2:port2", "ip3:port3"
```

I've also noted that you've included `localhost` in the contact points:

```
Failed to add contact point: "127.0.0.1";"172.30.0.2";"172.30.0.3";"172.30.0.4";"172.30.0.5";"172.30.0.6"
```

If you have a node that is only listening for client connections on `localhost` then it is configured incorrectly and you need to fix its configuration.

Finally, if your goal is to build a cluster for app development, you might want to consider using [Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) so you don't have to worry about configuring/maintaining your own Cassandra installation. With Astra DB, you can launch a cluster on the free tier with literally just 5 clicks in just over a minute with no credit card required. Cheers!